# Convert T-SQL query to ANSI SQL-99 standard

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm studying for the SQL Server querying exam, and I got a demo of some practice questions from a website. One of the questions asks to pull from two tables (`Customers` and `Orders`), using the first initial as an alias, find the most recent order for each customer, and order it with the most recent orders first. `Adventureworks` has tables just like this (`Sales.SalesOrderHeader` and `Sales.Customer`), so I created this query and thought I had it solved.

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, 
    MAX(o.OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customerid) AS MostRecentOrderDate
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader o 
INNER JOIN 
    Sales.Customer c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
ORDER BY 
    OrderDate DESC
```

But... at the end of the question it says to make sure it conforms to ANSI SQL-99 standard.

So I checked this code on

http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser99/index.tml#parser

and it tells me

> *The following features outside Core SQL-99 are used:
>
>   T611, Elementary OLAP operations
>
>   F391, Long identifiers*

Here's the definition of things included in T611 Elementary OLAP operations:

- Window functions (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, and DENSE_RANK)
- Unnamed window specifications:

  - window partitioning (PARTITION BY)
  - window ordering (ORDER BY)
  - window framing (ROWS/RANGE PRECEDING/FOLLOWING)
- null ordering

I'm not sure as to the exact reason why I'm getting the "Long Identifiers" error, but here's a link from Microsoft that has some stuff on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh544365(v=sql.105).aspx

Idk if this will actually help on the exam or not, but I was interested as to the answer.

Comment: I am not a genius regarding the ANSI 99 standard, but doesnt it also support GROUP BY, JOIN plus MAX... what else would you require to solve your problem?

Comment: "The following features outside Core SQL-99 are used:" -- Those features are part of SQL-99. They're optional, so implementations don't have to support them. Core SQL-99 is the bits of SQL-99 that all implementations are required to support, but SQL-99 is significantly more than merely Core SQL-99, and it's not clear from your question whether you can use all of it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know what the difference was. It doesn't specify in the question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previously accepted answer to this question produces an error when tested on the adventureworks sample database

> Column "SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY
>   clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
>   the GROUP BY clause.

There is a problem with the `order by` clause.
You can fix it by using

```
select C.LastName, max(O.OrderDate) as MROD
from SalesLT.Customer C inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader O
on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
group by C.LastName
order by max(O.OrderDate) Desc
```

or

```
select C.LastName, max(O.OrderDate) as MROD
from SalesLT.Customer C inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader O
on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
group by C.LastName
order by MROD Desc
```

Both these examples pass the sql-99 validator test, but only when I use a short name, such as MROD for the max(O.OrderDate) alias, instead of MostRecentOrderDate.

and also, I just passed the exam in question.

Comment: F391 appears for backward compatibility and can safely be ignored. SQL-89 only allowed identifiers to be up to 18 characters in length. SQL-99 allows identifiers up to 128 in length characters.

Answer (score 3):

Long identifier error is due to the fact that the identifier length is more that 30 characters.
try this query it works ::

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, 
    MAX(o.OrderDate) AS mrod
FROM 
    SalesOrderHeader o 
INNER JOIN 
    Customer c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
group by c.customerID
ORDER BY 
    o.OrderDate DESC
```

Comment: +1 just tried the exact same thing in the given SQL-99 validator to be sure

Comment: There were 2 issues one with identifier length and another one usage of analytical functions

Comment: What's dumb is that the question called for that specific name 'MostRecentOrderDate' for the name of the field. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select c.CustomerID, 
       MAX(o.OrderDate), 
from  SalesOrderHeader o
INNER JOIN Customer c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
group by o.CustomerID 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: That will return a different result than the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ORDER BY` is an elementary OLAP operation. You can safely remove it, your data just may not be displayed in the way you'd like.

The long identifier error is because you are referencing `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_CATALOG_NAME`. In other words, your `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` bit. You should be able to just reference the information schema catalog name, in your case `SalesOrderHeader` and `Customer` without specifying `Sales.`.

Answer (score 0):

By SQL-99 they *might* just mean user INNER JOIN and ON rather than joining in the WHERE clause.